Latency in Speech to text conversion using Azure cognitive services
I have a voice bot that takes speech input from users, the speech is converted to text and then text processing is done. I am getting latency >400 for speech to text conversion. How can I reduce this latency?
I have tried using asynchronous streaming and continuous recognition, but did not see major reduction in the latency.

Hi @retrixsvk, can you share your code snippet for more understanding.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
